# Send email on task list insert

Tags: tasks, email-alert

Can someone tell me how to tweak my code so the email alerts are sent out when my list of tasks is inserted?

```
global class  sched_TeamMemberExpiration implements Schedulable {

    //Make class schedulable    
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {        
        CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime
                          FROM CronTrigger WHERE Id = :ctx.getTriggerId()];

        //Get List of Team Members
        list<Account_Counselor__c> TeamMembers = new list<Account_Counselor__c>();
        date d                      = system.today().addDays(-60);
        date d2                     = system.today().addDays(-14);

        TeamMembers                 =[Select Fields and Criteria];

        List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
        RecordType TaskType = [Select Id from RecordType WHERE Name = 'Account Admin Task'];       

        //Loop through Team Members
        for(Account_Counselor__c TM:TeamMembers){

            string lastdate = null;

            //Fix Date
            if(tm.Last_Overall_Date__c != null){
                lastdate = tm.Last_Overall_Date__c.format();
            } else {
                lastdate = 'Never';
            }

              Task t            = new Task();
              t.Subject         = 'Inactive Team Member detected! - ' + TM.Hub_Name__r.Name;
              t.Type            = 'Account Administration';

              t.Description     = TM.Hub_Name__r.Name + 
                                    ' is no longer active on this account.  Their last activity on this account was on: ' + 
                                    lastdate + 
                                    '. \r\n' + 'Please remove this employee from the Team Members section of the Account page in CRM, as well as from any other applicable enrollment or client systems.';

              t.WhatId          = TM.Account__c;
              t.RecordTypeId    = TaskType.Id;
              t.OwnerId         = TM.Account__r.Backup_Owner__c;

              taskList.add(t);


        } //End for each Team Member loop

        insert taskList;  

    } //end schedudle class
} //end main class
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here is how you do it for other searchers.

```
for(Account_Counselor__c TM:TeamMembers){

            string lastdate = null;

            //Fix Date
            if(tm.Last_Overall_Date__c != null){
                lastdate = tm.Last_Overall_Date__c.format();
            } else {
                lastdate = 'Never';
            }

            Task t              = new Task();
            t.Subject           = 'Inactive Team Member detected! - ' + TM.Hub_Name__r.Name;
            t.Type          = 'Account Administration';

            t.Description       = TM.Hub_Name__r.Name + 
                ' is no longer active on this account.  Their last activity on this account was on: ' + 
                lastdate + 
                '. \r\n' + 'Please remove this employee from the Team Members section of the Account page in CRM, as well as from any other applicable enrollment or client systems.';

            t.WhatId            = TM.Account__c;
            t.RecordTypeId  = TaskType.Id;
            t.OwnerId           = TM.Account__r.Backup_Owner__c;

            Database.DMLOptions dlo = new Database.DMLOptions();
            dlo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = TRUE;
            t.setOptions(dlo);

            taskList.add(t);


        } //End for each Team Member loop

        insert taskList;
```